# how can i make models unique in Django together

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted to have 3 models TvSeries, Season and Episode.
any Episode should be only for one season if a specific TvSeries, and that specific Season should be only for one TvSeries
I'm defining my models like this

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


class Season(models.Model):
    season = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Episode(models.Model):
    episode = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but in this case  any season can be for any episode and every espisode i make I can choose a season and a complete difference TvSeries like this:

```
testfilm1 -> season1(id=1) -> episode 1
testfilm2-> season(id=1) -> episode 2
```

the season that is for testfilm1 can be a user in any other movie.
I tried this with unique_together but no chance.

Comment: A season can only contain one `Movie`, and an `Episode` only one `Season`, it is however unclear to me why you added a link from `Episode` to `Movie` since that relation already exists through `Season`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the season that is for `testfilm1` can be a user in any other movie. I tried this with unique_together but no chance.

**No,** you have added a `ForeignKey` in `Season` to `Movie`, and that means that every `Season` is linked to *exactly one* `Movie` (if you add `null=True`, it can be linked to *no* `Movie` at all).

Of course if we follow the relation in reverse, it means that a `Movie` can have *zero*, *one* or *more* `Season`s attached to it, and that every `Season` can have *zero*, *one* or *more* `Episode`s attached to it. But that seems logical. But an `Episode` can only belong to *exactly* one `Season` and a `Season` can only belong to *one* `Movie`.

What is strange however is that you define a `ForeignKey` from `Episode` to `Movie`. This makes no sense, since the movie simply follows the path of the `Season` and then to the `Movie`. You therefore probably should *remove* the `movie` attribute on the `Episode` model.

In case you fequently query for the `movie` of an `Episode`, we can define a property, like:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    episode = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def movie(self):
        return Movie.objects.get(season__episode=self)
```

The hierarcy you describe is therefore impossible. Either it is:

```
testfilm 1 -> season 1 -> episode 1
testfilm 1 -> season 1 -> episode 2
```

or it is:

```
testfilm 1 -> season 1 -> episode 1
testfilm 2 -> season 2 -> episode 2
```

Comment: thank you . and how can i first choose the movie in Django admin then it shows the  season for that movie? because if i want to choose the season that would be so hard to find such thing.

Comment: @Stick: by creating a custom admin form.